# Any Eulerian trail which is not an Eulerian circuit must start and end at an odd vertex.

Tags: proof-verification, graph-theory, induction, eulerian-path

Theorem Any Eulerian trail which is not an Eulerian circuit must start and end at an odd vertex.

https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Characteristics_of_Traversable_Graph

Proof:

> Let G be a graph.
>
> Suppose all the vertices are even, that is, there are no odd vertices.
>
> Then G is Eulerian, and the result holds.
>
> Similarly, by the same result, if G is Eulerian, it is by definition
>   traversable.
>
> So the question of graphs all of whose vertices are even is settled.
>
> Sufficient Condition Suppose G is a connected graph for which exactly
>   two vertices u,v are odd.
>
> Let G′ be the graph formed by adding the edge uv.
>
> Note that if there is already an edge uv in G, that will mean there is
>   now more than one edge uv in G′.
>
> Thus G′ will then be a multigraph or loop-multigraph, and uv a
>   multiple edge.
>
> Then G′ will have all its vertices even, and thus by the above result
>   be Eulerian and by definition traversable.
>
> Such an Eulerian circuit that traverses G′ can be written, for
>   example, P′=(v,w,x,…,t,u,v).
>
> Let us then remove the final edge uv from P′ to get the path
>   P=(v,w,x,…,t,u).
>
> It follows that the path P=(v,w,x,…,t,u) is a path in G which includes
>   all edges in G.
>
> Hence P traverses G and so G is traversable.
>
> We note that u and v are the odd vertices of G.
>
> Necessary Condition Suppose a graph G is traversable.
>
> Then it has a Eulerian trail P.
>
> If P is a circuit, then G is Eulerian and therefore has all even
>   vertices.
>
> Now, suppose P=(v,w,x,…,t,u) is not a circuit.
>
> Let G′ be the graph formed by adding the edge uv.
>
> Then the path P′=(v,w,x,…,t,u,v) is an Eulerian circuit and so G is
>   Eulerian.
>
> Hence all the vertices of G′ are even.
>
> So the degrees of vertices u and v in G (and no other) are odd.
>
> Again, we note that u and v are the odd vertices of G.
>
> Hence the result.
>
> ◼

I think this proof lacks a base case, an inductive hypothesis, and inductive step, so it is incomplete. I think the author adds edge $uv$ and removes the edge $uv$ as part of an attempt to do induction. Have I listed all the errors of the proof correctly?

Comment: I don't think the author is trying to prove by induction.  If you want to avoid multigraphs, you can add a vertex and connect it to the two odd vertices of $G$.  Removing that vertex and its two incident edges produces that trail from the circuit just as in this proof.

Comment: Is proving the theorem by induction possible?

Comment: The sufficiency part of the theorem for Euler circuits may be proved thus: Suppose $G$ is even and connected.  Draw an arbitrary circuit in $G$.  If it uses all the edges, we are done.  Otherwise what is left is still an even graph, though not necessarily connected.  There is at least one vertex on the circuit whose edges are not all in the circuit.  The connected components of all such vertices have fewer edges than $G$.  This allows you to apply induction to them and then merge all the circuits into one Euler circuit.